# C# Overriding default interface methods

Tags: c#, .net, .net-5

Is it possible to override default interface methods in another interface?

Assume I have the following code:

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        IOriginal origOrig = new Original();
        IOriginal origInh = new Inherited();
        IInherited inherited = new Inherited();
        
        Console.WriteLine($"IOriginal Original: {origOrig.Method()}");
        Console.WriteLine($"IOriginal Inherited: {origInh.Method()}");
        Console.WriteLine($"IInherited Inherited: {inherited.Method()}");
    }
}

public interface IOriginal
{
    string Method() => "original";
}

public interface IInherited : IOriginal
{
    string Method() => "inherited";
}

public class Inherited : IInherited {}
public class Original : IOriginal {}
```

The output is

```
IOriginal Original: original
IOriginal Inherited: original
IInherited Inherited: inherited
```

However, I would like to override the method in `IInherited` interface, so it produces this:

```
IOriginal Original: original
IOriginal Inherited: inherited
IInherited Inherited: inherited
```

In the [C# 8 specification proposal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods#overrides-in-interfaces), it was proposed by doing this:

```cs
interface IA
{
    void M() { WriteLine("IA.M"); }
}
interface IB : IA
{
    override void IA.M() { WriteLine("IB.M"); } // explicitly named
}
interface IC : IA
{
    override void M() { WriteLine("IC.M"); } // implicitly named
}
```

But in the official release, it is not working?

```
Compilation error: The modifier 'override' is not valid for this item
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Using `string IOriginal.Method()` [seems to work?](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEUCuA7NAExAGoAfAAQCYAGAWAChqBGRxigZgAJqfmB2RgG9GXMTypVR4kQ3HyuASQDyUAJYBzNXgCGAGy7RNqzVwC8XPDADuXE1t16AFAEoA3NIVL72/YfUaingAFuaWNkohMOoYMISuHnJeSkHB0WqxhFzaaTFxYVa2qemZCZ4K5fIUzACcTgAkAEQqAb4GPo4gXEJGGvYAdACyMBjBEPEuAL6N7pXi1XVNLZptkbkZcV09AalDI2MT07NJXgsNzcV5WZcbxN05JXF7o+OuR4nyk4xfDOzc2rEoAAzHRgGDeVqOYTlao0LjDF4TcwAPi4jV6bUaiR+f2yeEBILBKSiVy4XWWDn00JOfDhFLazwOrhRaIeVyx3zYTG4vBumTJxPW/KEP04EjskL85I6fhFQA) I can't find any docs saying this though. This language docs got rubbish after C# 6 or so

Comment: Oh yes it works!

Comment: Thanks! You can add it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using:

```
interface IB : IA
{
    void IA.M() { WriteLine("IB.M"); } // explicitly named
}
```

[appears to work](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEUCuA7NAExAGoAfAAQCYAGAWAChqBGRxigZgAJqfmB2RgG9GXMTypVR4kQ3HyuASQDyUAJYBzNXgCGAGy7RNqzVwC8XPDADuXE1t16AFAEoA3NIVL72/YfUaingAFuaWNkohMOoYMISuHnJeSkHB0WqxhFzaaTFxYVa2qemZCZ4K5fIUzACcTgAkAEQqAb4GPo4gXEJGGvYAdACyMBjBEPEuAL6N7pXi1XVNLZptkbkZcV09AalDI2MT07NJXgsNzcV5WZcbxN05JXF7o+OuR4nyk4xfDOzc2rEoAAzHRgGDeVqOYTlao0LjDF4TcwAPi4jV6bUaiR+f2yeEBILBKSiVy4XWWDn00JOfDhFLazwOrhRaIeVyx3zYTG4vBumTJxPW/KEP04EjskL85I6fhFQA).

I can't find any C# docs saying that this is the correct syntax however!

Comment: It works, however it breaks `CA1033` rule https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1033, so it is the right way?

Comment: I think CA1033 is confused there: it's meant for explicit interface implementations on classes. Might be worth raising an issue? This thread backs up the syntax: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2337